# Can I just upgrade my Acer from Vista to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, compatibility

I'm using an Acer 4720z with Vista Home Premium OS 32 bit. I would like to upgrade to Windows 7 32 bit. Is it possible? Do I also need to install driver software?

Answer (score 4):

The first step to do before you consider upgrading is go to the manufacturer website, [Acer](http://www.acer.com/worldwide/selection.html), and verify they have Windows 7 32-bit drivers for your model of computer. I would download those drivers to a flash drive prior to performing your upgrade.

If you have a Windows 7 upgrade disc, you will be able to install it inplace over Vista 32-bit and it should preserve your settings and data.

The default drivers will be installed and may look fine, but then should install the manufacturer drivers to make sure everything is working under the supported drivers.

Comment: +1 Drivers will be key.  While Windows 7 may have some drivers in the OS, best to be sure. Did one laptop(Dell) and still have two devices with no drivers.  They are not critical so no big deal.